# Movie where a group of soldiers encounter a temple that is not in the real world

Tags: story-identification

I rented it on DVD from Blockbuster, possibly around 15 years ago. I think it's a group of American soldiers lost in Korea (might even be a Korean movie), who get trapped in a temple that is not in the real world. It might not be a temple. but is a large old building which is not normally seen.

Not a mainstream film, more like one of those Tartan Asia films as I recall. Could be way out on that though. These are modern-ish soldiers with assault rifles and such.

I think they are warned by locals not to go there. It's supernatural, not a man made trap or anything

Comment: Do you remember anything else about it?  When you saw it?  Anything can be useful!

Comment: Not a lot to go on. Can you remember anything about the characters? Were they all men or were there some women? What were their ages? How did you know it was a temple? How were they trapped. Was it by accident or by design?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Myth_(film)

Comment: Rented it on DVD from Blockbuster, possibly around 15 years ago. I think it's a group of american soldiers lost. It might not be a temple. but is a large old building which is not normally seen. Not a mainstream film, more like one of those Tartan Asia films as I recall. Could be way out on that tho..These are modern-ish soldiers with assault rifles and such

Comment: I think they are warned by locals not to go there. It's supernatural not a man made trap or anything

Comment: [R-Point](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9b8WhQATBv8)?

Comment: I think that's it !!! I've wracked my brains for years trying to remember it because I would like to watch it again. Thank you

Comment: Found it on e-bay £1.99 delivered !!

Comment: @Tim - Glad I could help. I think this highlights the importance of putting as much information into the question as you possibly can. Even minor details can mean the difference between found/not-found.

Comment: @Richard Oops, I clobbered your edit. Nice find btw :-)

Comment: @Tim - Don't forget to accept the answer :-)

Answer (score 5):

This is [R-Point](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0417072/), a low-budget South Korean horror film and the winner of the coveted "worst lit trailer" award.

Comment: For the record, this film looks *awful*. Instead of watching this, you might consider doing something more worthwhile such as visiting an elderly relative, learning to say the alphabet backwards or trying to get your slinky to go all the way down the stairs without stopping once